# Desktop integration for electron app in appImage format

Tags: electron, electron-builder, appimage

I have created my electron app and built it on .deb format using electron-builder. But to enable auto-update, now I have switched into appImage format. But, for desktop integration to work, I have to use an external library as per their [documentation](https://www.electron.build/configuration/appimage).

[image]

As of my understanding, every user has to install `AppImageLauncher` for this to work. I think this is not a good method to distribute my app. Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Notice that your users will still be able to run your binaries. AppImageLauncher is not mandatory for this. It only adds the "Create desktop entry" bit.

Comment: Yes, but with limited accessibility. Without desktop integration, the app name won't show on the menu, so that the user has to open the appImage directory and run. Also, the auto-startup won't work. Is there any other workaround to achieve this?

Comment: Unlike with Snap or Flatpack distributions don't want to include tools (or implement) for proper AppImage integration. Other alternatives to perform this are can be found here: https://github.com/AppImage/awesome-appimage#desktop-integration